# Mutual Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, mathematics, word, wordplay

I say:

> My prefix is my abbreviation.
>
> My infix is.
>
> My suffix is seeing something.
>
> Together, I need someone like you.

You say:

> My prefix is a place.
>
> My infix is eating something.
>
> My suffix is suspicious by its presence.
>
> Together, you cannot let the one like me be nothing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe:

> You are **DIVISION** and I am **DENOMINATOR**

*My prefix is my abbreviation.*
*My infix is.*
*My suffix is seeing something.*
*Together, I need someone like you.*

> Prefix: **DIV** is the abbrevation for **DIVISION**, common in programming and proofs, and also the prefix
>  Infix: **IS** is the infix for **DIVISION**
>  Suffix: **VISION** is seeing something
>  Together: You need a **DENOMINATOR** to perform **DIVISION**

*My prefix is a place.*
*My infix is eating something.*
*My suffix is suspicious by its presence.*
*Together, you cannot let the one like me be nothing.*

> Prefix: **DEN**, a room or wild animal's lair is a place
>  Infix: **NOM**, to eat something loudly or with enjoyment
>  Suffix: **TOR** is an open source tool for anonymous communication and web browsing, that while having legitimate uses to protect privacy, has gained notoriety as a tool used to carry out illicit activities online. Suspicious!
>  Together: **DENOMINATOR** cannot be 0, otherwise **DIVISION** is undefined

Comment: The words are correct. Now please work on the only hint you're missing! :)

Comment: @DannyuNDos: rot13(Vf vg orpnhfr bs ZVANGBEL, juvpu zrnaf bzvabhf be guerngravat?)

Comment: rot13(Bqqyl rabhtu, Qe. Qbbsrafuzvegm sebz Cuvarnf naq Sreo nyjnlf anzrq uvf vairagvbaf gb raq va -VANGBE.) However, this just may be a coincidence.  :)

Comment: rot13(Gunaxf sbe gur uvag! Vg pnzr hc jura frnepuvat sbe **VANGBE** zhygvcyr gvzrf ohg V whfg arire znqr gur pbaarpgvba orgjrra gung naq orvat fhfcvpvbhf. Zvtug arrq gb jngpu gur fubj un!)

Comment: rot13(V arire urneq bs gung fubj. Uvag: Gur fhssvk V vagraqrq vf whfg "gbe".)

Comment: rot13(Nu! Gunaxf. Unir arire qbar bar bs gurfr orsber naq nffhzrq nyy yrggref unq gb or vapyhqrq. Ubcr gung jbexf.)